# Spring tool application failed to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Anyone know how to solve below issue?

> The following method did not exist:
>
> 'void
> org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletContainerInitializer(javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer,
> java.util.Set)'
>
> The calling method's class,
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory,
> was loaded from the following location:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/C:/Users/Janice/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.6/spring-boot-2.7.6.jar!/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.class
> ```
>
> The called method's class, org.apache.catalina.Context, is available
> from the following locations:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/C:/Users/Janice/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/org/apache/catalina/Context.class
> ```
>
> The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following
> locations:
>
> ```
> org.apache.catalina.Context: file:/C:/Users/Janice/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains
> compatible versions of the classes
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory
> and org.apache.catalina.Context

I expected to upgrade version for tomcat-embed-core to version 10.1.4

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: JDK version ? full pom.xml ? How to start your application ? java -jar xxx.jar ? Your Spring Boot Application class source ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot deploy Spring Boot 2.7.x or lower to Tomcat 10, because Spring Boot 2.7 uses Jakarta EE 8, which uses the `javax.*` namespace, while Tomcat 10 is Jakarta EE 9 or higher, which uses the `jakarta.*` namespace. This is a big breaking change in the Java world, and you cannot just mix and match incompatible dependencies.

You either need to upgrade to Spring Boot 3, or you need to downgrade to Tomcat 9.

Also, in this case, you should let Spring Boot control the version of `tomcat-embed-core`, and not specify the version yourself. [Spring Boot 2.7.7](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) specifies `tomcat-embed-core` 9.0.70 (search for `tomcat-embed-core`), while [Spring Boot 3.0.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) specifies `tomcat-embed-core` 10.1.4. Don't try to change it yourself, especially not to incompatible version. Changing to different minor or patch versions will usually work, but should generally not be done either because it increases your maintenance overhead, where otherwise you'll only need to increase the Spring Boot version to receive new *compatible* dependency versions.